# sshd: How to enable PAM authentication for specific users under

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

I am using sshd, and allow logins with public key authentication.

I want to allow select users to log in with a PAM two-factor authentication module.

Is there any way I can allow PAM two-factor authentication for a specific user?

By the same token - I only want to enable password authentication for specific accounts. I want my SSH daemon to reject the password authentication attempts to thwart would-be hackers into thinking that I will not accept password authentication - except for the case in which someone knows my heavily guarded secret account, which *is* password enabled. I want to do this for cases in which my SSH clients will not let me do either secret key, or two-factor authentication.

Comment: Which two-factor product?

Comment: google-authenticator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could probably handle this with the `pam_listfile` module.  Create an `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file that looks something like:

```
auth requisite  pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow file=/etc/authusers
auth sufficient pam_securid.so
auth required   pam_deny.so
```

This would allow only people listed in `/etc/authusers` the ability to authenticate with a two-factor module (in our case, secureid).  I haven't actually tested this configuration, but the theory is sound.

You could make it simpler by allowing *anyone* to authenticate using two factor authentication; presumably, only those people with the appropriate devices/configuration would be able to succeed, so you'd get effectively the same behavior.

Comment: I'm doing something sorta similar - I have sshd allow Chal/Resp and Secret Key. Only one account is actually configured for the Google-Authenticator challenge/response - so other accounts MUST use the Secret Key only. I guess this is as good as I am going to get...

Answer (score 7):

In order to disable two-factor auth for users without *Google Authenticator* configured, add the `nullok` option in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth   required   pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

For more details see: https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam#setting-up-a-user

Answer (score 5):

Using the below solution, PAM Module(google authenticator) can be disable for specific users-

1) Create a user group on the Linux instance. MFA/PAM will be disabled for users present in this new group-

```
sudo groupadd <groupname>
```

2) Create User or add existing user to newly created group-

```
sudo useradd <username>
sudo usermod -a -G <groupname> <username>
```

3) Edit /etc/pam.d/sshd file and add the below statement to skip PAM module for the newly created group-

```
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup <groupname>
```

Optional-

If full access is required for this new group then add below line to visudo file-

```
%<groupname>ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

When a user will be created and added to the new group, MFA will be skipped for those users.

Referenced from -[TechManyu Blog](https://www.techmanyu.com/disable-linux-pam-module-for-specific-users/)